# Once I've turned on the crane, what do I do?

Tags: donkey-kong-game-watch

In [Donkey Kong](http://pica-pic.com/#/donkey_kong/), once I've turned on the crane, what do I need to do? If I go right I fall off and die, and I can't go back down the ladder and along. How do I get to the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have turned on the crane, you should notice that the crane hook starts swinging.

You need to wait until the hook swings into the position closest to you, and then jump on it.

The crane will carry you up and you can loosen the struts holding up Donkey Kong's platform.